# Im looking to find AWS instances over X days old to shut down

Tags: json, bash, jq

This is part of a bigger project but I am in this first instance trying to collate AWS instances over X days old.
I am struggling to work with the formatted dates or jq :/

I have tried a number of formatting ideas (unix time, short date etc)
Ultimately it would be easier to work with the date field in the json that is brought back by the awscli

Example JSON

```
aws cloudformation list-stacks
```

```
{
    "StackSummaries": [
       {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-029e8e947a9c", 
            "DriftInformation": {
                "StackDriftStatus": "NOT_CHECKED"
            }, 
            "TemplateDescription": "Testing - SINGLE", 
            "CreationTime": "2019-04-23T15:25:22.757Z", 
            "StackName": "HAPPYHARRY123456789", 
            "StackStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-0a4e84363f34", 
            "DriftInformation": {
                "StackDriftStatus": "NOT_CHECKED"
            }, 
            "TemplateDescription": "Testing - SINGLE", 
            "CreationTime": "2019-04-15T14:31:42.515Z", 
            "StackName": "HAPPYHARRY123789456", 
            "StackStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-50faeb5394d2", 
            "LastUpdatedTime": "2018-01-23T15:44:53.640Z", 
            "TemplateDescription": "Lambda Gateway", 
            "CreationTime": "2018-01-23T15:44:48.134Z", 
            "StackName": "BARRYLAMBDA", 
            "StackStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE", 
            "DriftInformation": {
                "StackDriftStatus": "NOT_CHECKED"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am looking for a date to kill the cloudformation
I've tried lots of date formatting including using jq to extract CreationTime and covert to Unix time and minus from today in Unix time.. blah, blah, blah

Now I'm here...
I created an iso time to match the aws time

```
#how far back do I wish
daysback=7 

#iso date of today
today=$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z") 

#take daysback from indicated time of aws instance
killdate=`date -d "$today - $daysback days" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z"` 

#the killdate > kill all older than
echo $killdate

#2019-04-16T16:10:20.000Z
```

pseudo I want
looking in json, find any stack with a date further back than killdate and list stack name only if starts with HAPPY which I achieve with

```
echo $json |jq '.StackSummaries[]' | jq -r 'select (.CreationTime>"$killdate") | .StackName' | awk '/^HAPPY/'
```

I am using this to prove my syntax

This gives me no output

```
echo $json |jq '.StackSummaries[]' | jq 'select (.CreationTime<"$killdate") | .CreationTime'
```

This gives me everything

```
echo $json |jq '.StackSummaries[]' | jq 'select (.CreationTime>"$killdate") | .CreationTime'
```

I would have expected the below

```
"2019-04-15T14:31:42.515Z"
"2018-01-23T15:44:48.134Z"
```

and once returning the stackname instead

```
"HAPPYHARRY123789456"
```

Can anyone see where im going wrong and why it isnt returning what i wish??

## FOUND MY ANSWER WHILST WRITING THIS SO PUT IT HERE FOR OTHERS

```
echo $json |jq '.StackSummaries[]' | jq --arg kill $killdate 'select (.CreationTime < $kill ) | .CreationTime'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $json |jq '.StackSummaries[]' | jq --arg kill $killdate 'select (.CreationTime < $kill ) | .CreationTime'
```

The argument needs to come from outside the selection :/

thanks

Comment: There is no need to call jq twice.